# Why is MQTT not connecting with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I have a weird issue trying to connect to an `MQTT` server with `NODEJS`:

If I connect to the `MQTT` server and I do not get a connect it just hangs.

If I do it with the command line I see data so network, server etc is all good.

If I use a port thats wrong then command line gives me a valid reject message but NODE just hangs.

Command line is:

```
mosquitto_sub -h 10.10.10.30 -p 1883 -t sim
```

My code is completely basic:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var MQTT_TOPIC          = "sim";
var MQTT_ADDR           = "10.10.10.30";
var MQTT_PORT           = 1883;
var client = mqtt.connect({host: MQTT_ADDR, port : MQTT_PORT, debug: true});

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC, function() {
        client.on('message', function(topic, message, packet) {
            console.log(topic + ": '" + message);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What version of mosquitto are you running?

Comment: Had the same problem. Works when using mosquitto_sub, but doesn't work when implement the subscriber in nodejs.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, and figured out a solution. I'm no node.js expert, so it was just a case of trial and error. Maybe somebody else can detail the true problem.

This connection string works for me: `var client  = mqtt.connect(MQTT_ADDR,{clientId: 'bgtestnodejs', protocolId: 'MQIsdp', protocolVersion: 3, connectTimeout:1000, debug:true});`

Full example below:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var MQTT_TOPIC          = "hello";
var MQTT_ADDR           = "mqtt://192.168.0.105";
var MQTT_PORT           = 1883;

/* This is not working as expected */
//var client = mqtt.connect({host: MQTT_ADDR, port:MQTT_PORT},{clientId: 'bgtestnodejs'});

/* This works... */
var client  = mqtt.connect(MQTT_ADDR,{clientId: 'bgtestnodejs', protocolId: 'MQIsdp', protocolVersion: 3, connectTimeout:1000, debug:true});

client.on('connect', function () {
    client.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC);
    client.publish(MQTT_TOPIC, 'Hello mqtt');
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    // message is Buffer
    console.log(message.toString());
    client.end();
});

client.on('error', function(){
    console.log("ERROR")
    client.end()
})
```

Mosquitto seems to require that the protocolId and protocolVersion is set as above. 
Additionally, notice that the host and port is not included in the options, but instead given as the first argument.

If I read the documentation correct, the host and port arguments should NOT be given as part of the options, but as a "servers" option, before the options. See this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#mqttconnecturl-options). I can't get the syntax from that link to work, but the code lines above, seems to the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent hours trying to fix this until I found your post!!

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you so much! Failed to understand why when IP was used instead of a domain name, the mqtt.connect() doesn't work.

Comment: Looking into doc of https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt npm, it seems like the problem comes from version of mosquitto running. for Mosquitto < 1.3 (only support MQTT protocol v 3.1) then the configuration is required: {
  protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
  protocolVersion: 3
}.

Answer (score 1):

On today, in current mqtt 4.2.5 I found the error message while use mqtt.connect: "URL is not defined". I found that if I use mqtt 4.1.0 version no this bug found. So you can temporary specify it in the package json and reinstall the mqtt:

```
"mqtt": "4.1.0"
```

and then

```
npm install mqtt
```

Comment: @ichimaru you can try to remove previous version of the mqtt in the node_modules in case if nothing specified on the other version found in your source code