# Cannot connect to Eclipse Mosquitto broker using Node.js mqtt library

Tags: node.js, docker, mqtt, mosquitto

I am running Eclipse Mosquitto on a local docker container on 172.17.0.2:1883

I am able to publish/subscribe using MQTT.fx client but now trying to connect to the broker from node and haven't been able to.

The topic is "sensors"

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
e747c86b6ec1        eclipse-mosquitto   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours          0.0.0.0:1883->1883/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9001->9001/tcp   adoring_varahamihira
```

When I inspect the IP address

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' e747c86b6ec1
172.17.0.2
```

I am trying to use the following node server to connect to my MQTT broker but the 'connect' event never seems to happen.

```
// Note: I have an express server running but didn't include 
const mqtt = require("mqtt")

var MQTT_TOPIC = "sensors";
var MQTT_ADDR = "mqtt://172.17.0.2";
var MQTT_PORT = 1883;

var client = mqtt.connect(MQTT_ADDR, {
  port: MQTT_PORT,
  clientId: 'bgtestnodejs232323',
  protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
  protocolVersion: 3,
  connectTimeout: 1000,
  debug: true
});

client.on('connect', function () {
  console.log("connected!")
});

client.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err)``
  client.end()
})
```

When I run:

```
console.log(util.inspect(client))
```

The output is:

```
MqttClient {
  options:
   { protocol: 'mqtt',
     slashes: true,
     auth: null,
     host: '172.17.0.2',
     port: 1883,
     hostname: '172.17.0.2',
     hash: null,
     search: null,
     query: [Object: null prototype] {},
     pathname: null,
     path: null,
     href: 'mqtt://172.17.0.2',
     clientId: 'bgtestnodejs232323',
     protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
     protocolVersion: 3,
     connectTimeout: 1000,
     debug: true,
     defaultProtocol: 'mqtt',
     keepalive: 60,
     reschedulePings: true,
     reconnectPeriod: 1000,
     clean: true,
     resubscribe: true,
     customHandleAcks: [Function] },
  streamBuilder: [Function: wrapper],
  outgoingStore: Store { options: { clean: true }, _inflights: Map {} },
  incomingStore: Store { options: { clean: true }, _inflights: Map {} },
  queueQoSZero: true,
  _resubscribeTopics: {},
  messageIdToTopic: {},
  pingTimer: null,
  connected: false,
  disconnecting: false,
  queue: [],
  connackTimer:
   Timeout {
     _called: false,
     _idleTimeout: 1000,
     _idlePrev: [TimersList],
     _idleNext: [TimersList],
     _idleStart: 478,
     _onTimeout: [Function],
     _timerArgs: undefined,
     _repeat: null,
     _destroyed: false,
     [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
     [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1 },
  reconnectTimer: null,
  _storeProcessing: false,
  _packetIdsDuringStoreProcessing: {},
  nextId: 26898,
  outgoing: {},
  _firstConnection: true,
  _events:
   [Object: null prototype] {
     close: [ [Function], [Function], [Function] ],
     connect: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  stream:
   Socket {
     connecting: true,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        reading: false,
        onread: [Function: onStreamRead],
        onconnection: null,
        [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular] },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
        length: 0,
        pipes: [Writable],
        pipesCount: 1,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: false,
        sync: true,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: true,
        paused: false,
        emitClose: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        end: [Array],
        data: [Function: ondata],
        error: [Function: nop],
        close: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 4,
     _maxListeners: 1000,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 34,
        writing: false,
        corked: 1,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: [Object],
        lastBufferedRequest: [Object],
        pendingcb: 9,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 9,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: null,
     _server: null,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 5,
     [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
     [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
     [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 } }
```

I have been trying the suggestions in this answer: [Why is MQTT not connecting with NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347724/why-is-mqtt-not-connecting-with-nodejs)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: noticed that you run the broker on 1883, but then again I see that you use 9001 in your code. Is the 9001 the right port?

Comment: Apologies this was my mistake - I was experimenting with 9001. It doesn't work with 9001 or 1883. I will edit the question to be 1883 and appropriate output.

Comment: Where is the nodejs code running (docker host, or in another container on the same host)? Also add a `client.on('error', function(err){})`  callback so you can see why the client is not connecting.

Comment: Nodejs code is running on localhost. I do have the error handler in my code but it doesn't trigger (I edited it in above). Thanks again

Comment: By localhost you mean the machine that is hosting the docker engine?

Comment: It's not in docker at all - everything else in the setup is in a docker container but for my nodejs code I'm just running on a node server on my local machine. Could this be causing issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP address range 172.17.0.0/16 that is handed out to Docker containers by the Docker engine are part of the [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) set intended for private use.

In the case of Docker, they are used on the internal "bridge" network and only accessible from other docker containers or the machine hosting the Docker engine.

The `0.0.0.0:1883->1883/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9001->9001/tcp` output for the info of your mosquitto container shows that these ports have been exposed and are mapped to the host machines IP address. You should be able to connect if you change 172.17.0.2 for the IP address of the machine hosting the Docker engine.

Comment: I set it to  ```MQTT_ADDR = "mqtt://188.XXX.XXX.XX.";``` my local machine's IP address but still no error or connection. I think that your docker point could be the issue though, maybe I should try running my node server in a docker container? Thanks again!

Comment: You've still not answered the question, is everything running on the same machine, the nodejs and the docker containers?

Comment: Ah apologies! Yeah, it is all on the same machine

Comment: Thank you this helped me solve the problem. I was able to fix this issue by running my node server within a docker container. I was able to then connect to 172.17.0.2. I used this article for the Dockerfile and skeleton of nodejs file. http://study.ar-leung.net/node-js-mqtt-docker/ The command I used was ` docker run -it -p 9002:3002 -v $(pwd):/app mqtt-server /bin/bash ` and then ran ` node app/mqtt-server.js  `

Answer (score 2):

- Port 9001 is the websocket listener
- Port 1883 is the native MQTT listener

You are using the `mqtt://` schema for your broker URL which indicates the native MQTT protocol, yet you are forcing the use of port 9001.

If you want to use WebSockets then you should change the schema to `ws://`

If you want to use native MQTT then you need to change the port to 1883

Comment: Thank you, this was my mistake it should be 1883 but it still doesn't work. I have updated the question with port console log of client object. Thank you for your explanation it really helps me understand the default ports.