# How do I convert this command into MQTT.js?

Tags: react-native, mqtt, aws-iot

1. I already have an Aws IoT setup.
2. I have a react native simple app, running in android simulator.
3. I have implemented this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-native-mqtt.
4. I have my pem, crt and key stored in %USERPROFILE%\certs.
5. I run this command in my cmd `mqtt pub --cafile %USERPROFILE%\certs\root-ca.pem --cert %USERPROFILE%\certs\certificate.pem.crt --key %USERPROFILE%\certs\private.pem.key -d -h ******-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -t test -m "hello there"`
6. I checked. It showed up in Aws IoT Test Console, I Subscribed to `test`.

No error occurring so far.

I have this code in my react native:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
const fs = require('fs')

// const KEY = fs.readFileSync('%USERPROFILE%\certs\private.pem.key');
// const CERT = fs.readFileSync('%USERPROFILE%\certs\certificate.pem.crt');
// const CAfile = [fs.readFileSync('%USERPROFILE%\certs\root-ca.pem')];
const KEY = './aws/private.pem.key';
const CERT = './aws/certificate.pem.crt';
const CAfile = ['./aws/root-ca.pem'];

const options = {
  host: "******-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com",
  port: 8883,
  protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
  ca: CAfile,
  keyPath: KEY,
  certPath: CERT,
  secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method',
  protocolVersion: 3
};
const client  = mqtt.connect(options)

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('test', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish('test', 'Hello mqtt')
    }
  })
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
})
```

I have already tried using fs, its causing error `fs.readFileSync is not a function`
So, I am using this path `'./aws/private.pem.key'` `'./aws/certificate.pem.crt'` `'./aws/root-ca.pem'`

This is the error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8883/' failed: Error in
> connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> createBrowserWebSocket @ ws.js:108 browserStreamBuilder @ ws.js:134
> wrapper @ index.js:154
> ../../../../../../../../../Documents/_msit/iot/Round
> 2/mqttks/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js.MqttClient._setupStream @
> client.js:298 ../../../../../../../../../Documents/_msit/iot/Round
> 2/mqttks/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js.MqttClient._reconnect @
> client.js:938 (anonymous) @ client.js:958

I was wondering why its localhost even though I set the host.

So, my question, How do I convert this command that is working `mqtt pub --cafile %USERPROFILE%\certs\root-ca.pem --cert %USERPROFILE%\certs\certificate.pem.crt --key %USERPROFILE%\certs\private.pem.key -d -h ******-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -t test -m "hello there"` into MQTT.js, Javascript, mqtt.connect()?

Answer (score 1):

`host` and `port` are not specified in options.  Your connect() call should look something like this:

```
const HOST = "******-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com";
const PORT = 8883;

const options = {
  protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
  ca: CAfile,
  keyPath: KEY,
  certPath: CERT,
  secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method',
  protocolVersion: 3
};

var uri = "mqtt://" + HOST + ":" + PORT;

const client = mqtt.connect(uri, options);
```

Your question is similar to what has already been answered here on StackOverflow:  [Why is MQTT not connecting with NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347724/why-is-mqtt-not-connecting-with-nodejs)

Comment: it did not work on react-native, so i tried reactapp only, i got this error `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`